# How can i show product quantity after clicking 'configure' button during order process

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, adminhtml

When i create an order on admin page, you can see 'add product' button. After clicked it, you can see the configure option on grouped product and configurable product.

[image]

And i want it to show product quantity for easily placing order like this:

[image]

I attached a file related with this problem

> public_html/vendor/magento/module-grouped-product/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/composite/fieldset/Grouped.phtml

```
<table class="data-table admin__table-primary grouped-items-table" id="super-product-table">
            <thead>
                <tr class="headings">
                    <th class="col-id"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('ID') ?></th>
                    <th class="col-sku"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('SKU') ?></th>
                    <th class="col-name"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Product Name') ?></th>
                    <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)): ?>
                    <th class="col-price"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Price') ?></th>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() || $_skipSaleableCheck): ?>
                    <th class="col-qty"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?></th>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php if ($_hasAssociatedProducts): ?>
                <?php $i = 0 ?>
            <?php foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_item): ?>
                <tr class="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo(++$i % 2) ? 'even' : 'odd' ?>">
                    <td class="col-id"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getId() ?></td>
                    <td class="col-sku"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_item->getSku()) ?></td>
                    <td class="col-name"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></td>
                    <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)): ?>
                    <td class="col-price">
                        <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)): ?>
                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductPrice($_item) ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </td>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() || $_skipSaleableCheck): ?>
                    <td class="col-qty">
                    <?php if ($_item->isSaleable() || $_skipSaleableCheck) : ?>
                        <input type="text"
                               name="super_group[<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getId() ?>]"
                               id="super_group[<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getId() ?>]"
                               maxlength="12"
                               value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getQty()*1 ?>"
                               title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>"
                               class="input-text admin__control-text qty" />
                        <input type="hidden" value="1" price="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getCurrencyPrice($_item->getPrice()) ?>" qtyId="super_group[<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getId() ?>]" />
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    </td>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php else: ?>
               <tr>
                   <td class="empty-text" colspan="<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() || $_skipSaleableCheck): ?>4<?php else : ?>3<?php endif; ?>"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('No options of this product are available.') ?></td>
               </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```